# Failing to deploy java application to App Engine/Heroku

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my spring boot application to Google App Engine from IntelliJ but I get a weird error during the deployment about classes/symbols that cannot be found. It seem like the app build is failing because of some problem with the dependencies in the project (note: I have dependencies from maven and from external jars)

I tried to deploy with Heroku instead of App Engine but I got a similliar problem.

example of some of the errors:

```
cannot find symbol
remote:        [ERROR] symbol:   class GetMapping

cannot find symbol
remote:        [ERROR] symbol:   class RequestParam

package javax.persistence does not exist

package org.springframework.http does not exist

package org.aspectj.lang does not exist
```

it seems like all the packages that are missing are packages from the external jars and from maven.

Is there any way to fix this without moving all my jars to maven dependencies?
I don't want to move all those jars to maven because there are simply too many of them and I don't want them to interfere with my work in the pom file.